# Fhir $export custom location

Tags: hl7-fhir

For $export operations the HL7 Fhir spec says `Content-Location header with a url for subsequent status requests` for Response-Success. Has anyone found a way to direct output to a *location of their own choosing*?
Let's say I'm calling $export as part of a pipeline that generates a custom Url with my own GUID as part of the CDM GenerateSchema (for tracking purposes), I would like to be able to pass a Url to the $export call with *that* Url. I see $export is a ResourceType of OperationDefinition, which leads me to believe a customization is possible.
[OperationDefinition for $export](https://hl7.org/fhir/uv/bulkdata/OperationDefinition-export.html)
Right now I'm capturing the Content-Location from the output of the Web Activity and then copying the resultant ndjson files in a For Loop. It would be better to be able to cut out these steps and direct the output.
TIA

Comment: How would the data source know they would have write access to that location (or know how to manage authentication to write to that location?)

Comment: It would just be a configuration setting.

Comment: My point is that it's very difficult for a sever to know how to write data to a location they don't control.  There's no standard for how to authenticate or enable that.  Thus the protocol is designed for the server to decide where the data will be written and the client to retrieve the data from that location.